# strtok() returning NULL when there should be tokens remaining

Tags: c, arrays, strtok

I'm working on a basic shell and using strtok to break down a line into commands, then commands into arguments. However I'm running into issues with the tokenizer not returning all of the tokens it should.

For example, I feed in the string `ls -l; cat "foo.txt`. The tokenizer should return the commands `ls -l` and `cat "foo.txt"`. The commands should then be broken into arguments `ls`, `-l`, `cat`, and `"foo.txt"`. However, I get the following as my output.

```
prompt>ls -l; cat "foo"
Command: ls -l
Number of tokens in command: 2
Token : ls
Token : (null)
Number of tokens in command: 0
```

My relevant code is below:

```
char *commands = strtok(line, ";");
int count = 0;

//get # of commands on line
while(commands != NULL){
    count++;
    //printf("Command : %s\n", commands);
    commands = strtok(NULL, ";");
}

commands = strtok(line, ";");
char *command[count];

//build array of commands
for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
    if(commands != NULL){
        command[i] = commands;
        printf("Command: %s\n", command[i]);
    }
    commands = strtok(NULL, ";");
}

//Fork Loop
for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){

    //printf("Command: %s\n", command[i]);
    char *arglist = strtok(command[i], " ");
    int arglistc = 0;

    //Count number of args in command
    while(arglist != NULL){
        arglistc++;
        arglist = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }

    printf("Number of tokens in command: %d\n", arglistc);

    char *args[arglistc];
    arglist = strtok(command[i], " ");

    //Build array of args
    for(int j = 0; j < arglistc; j++){
        args[i] = arglist;
        printf("Arglist value : %s\n", arglist);
        printf("Token : %s\n", args[i]);
        arglist = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong as I looked up how to use strtok to populate an array and I'm doing just as the solution instructed.

Comment: How should I reinitialize it then? I need to loop through in order to get the count for the array. Or if there's a better way to get the array count I'll take either. I hate how many loops I need to use in this program, but my TA said this was the one of the simplest ways to do it.

Comment: Don't use `strtok()`, use `strpbrk()` or `strchr()` if it's a single delimiter.

Comment: Neither of those match what I'm looking for. I need to split the input string into substrings based on a delimiter, not find the first instance of a character in the string.

Comment: Oh, I see. That actually does work much better for getting my array length. Thanks!

Comment: Your approach implies here `char *command[count];` and here `char *args[arglistc];` that the C implementation in use supports V(ariable)L(enght)A(rrays)s, which are not around for <C99 and are optional for C11. So to stay portable you cannot use VLAs, which in turn raises the need to dynamically resize arrays for collecting data of an unknown number. Have a look at `realloc()`.

Comment: The Linux man page for strtok has an example that mimics your scenario. You have to use strtok_r for that purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The problem

`strtok` modifies the string you tokenize, replacing delimiters it finds with `0`. The result is a number of strings stored embedded in the original array for your string.

### Solution 1: Don't modify the array

`strchr` will find the first occurrence of a character, we can use it to count the number of tokens. **Just don't increment the count on loops where the following character is a delimiter.** Then you may use it again (or `strtok`) when you want to iterate over actual tokens.

You may also use `strpbrk` if you want to allow multiple delimiter options.

### Solution 2: Traverse the strings embedded in the array

Start the `"Token:"` loop at `command[i]` and move to `strtok(arglist + strlen(arglist) + 1, " ")` each step.

### Otherwise

This is C, there are of course other solutions.

Comment: The problem isn't outputting those details. That was there for debugging purposes. The problem is it's not storing things in the format I need them for a later part of the program. I need to either use a different method for getting the needed array length or find a way to reinitialize the string for tokenization.

Comment: Don't modify the string unless NECESSARY, use `strchr()`, for all of it.

Comment: The thing is `strtok()` sucks for many reasons. Ever since I hade trouble with it (specially because it's not reentrant and you can't parse multiple strings with it) I learned that using `strchr()`/`strstr()`/`strpbrk()` solves all the problems `strtok()` does but without all the problems. Specially, not needing to modify the string. Sometimes you want to extract portions from a string without touching it.

Comment: @iharob: Running `strtok()` on a working copy might help, still sometimes creating the copy is too expensive.

Comment: @alk Yes, `strtok()` is not useless, it's just hard to use right like `scanf()`. Also, I am not implying that one should copy the string, just try to do whatever you need but without touching it

Comment: uhm, what if 0 is in use by the char array? am I to understand that this function has undefined behaviour built into it?

Comment: @Barny 0 means the code 0, i.e. null character, not '0' which is code 48 in ASCII for example.